# Throwing errors to include http status codes

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, error-handling

I have written an API where I have separated the services from the controllers. In my service functions, I have defined simple checks to throw errors if they are met. My controller function now returns a 500 status code for each thrown error. Is there a way to specify the HTTP code when an error is thrown using the logic I have used?

Controller Function:

```
export const login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await loginUser(email, password);

        res.cookie('jwt', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true });

        return res.status(200).json({ accessToken });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error });
    }
};
```

Service Function:

```
export const loginUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    if (!email || !password) {
        throw new Error('All fields are required');
    }

    const user = await findUser(email);

    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('User does not exist');
    }

    const isValid = validPassword(password, user.password.salt, user.password.hash);

    if (isValid) {
        const { refreshToken, accessToken } = issueJWT(user._id);

        return { refreshToken, accessToken };
    } else {
        throw new Error('You entered the wrong password');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can create a function that takes the message, statusCode and data and creates an error with the provided info like this:

```
module.exports.generateError = (message, statusCode, data) => {
    const error = new Error(message);
    error.statusCode = statusCode;
    error.data = data || {};
    error.error = true;
    return error
}
```

And each time you can call:

```
throw generateError('You entered the wrong password',400);
```

instead of:

```
throw new Error('You entered the wrong password');
```